# service that uses pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm trying to run [wyoming-satellite](https://github.com/rhasspy/wyoming-satellite) on my ubuntu server. I can run it on the terminal the following code:

```
script/run --name 'xps' \
--uri 'tcp://0.0.0.0:10700' \
--mic-command 'parecord --property=media.role=phone --rate=16000 --channels=1 --format=s16le --raw' \
--snd-command 'paplay --property=media.role=announce --rate=16000 --channels=1 --format=s16le --raw' \
--snd-command-rate 16000  \
--vad \
--mic-auto-gain 5 \
--mic-noise-suppression 2 \
--done-wav /home/ignacio/wav/done.wav \
--awake-wav /home/ignacio/wav/awake.wav
```

But, I'm struggling to get it to run [as a service.](https://github.com/rhasspy/wyoming-satellite/blob/master/docs/tutorial_2mic.md#create-services). This is how my `wyoming-satellite.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wyoming Satellite
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1"
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ignacio/wyoming-satellite/script/run --name 'mini-server' \
--area 'Living Room'  \
--uri 'tcp://0.0.0.0:10700' \
--wake-uri 'tcp://127.0.0.1:10400' \
--mic-command 'parecord --property=media.role=phone --rate=16000 --channels=1 --format=s16le --raw' \
--snd-command 'paplay --property=media.role=announce --rate=16000 --channels=1 --format=s16le --raw' \
--snd-command-rate 16000  \
--done-wav /home/ignacio/wav/done.wav \
--awake-wav /home/ignacio/wav/awake.wav
WorkingDirectory=/home/ignacio/wyoming-satellite
User=ignacio
Restart=always
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Do I need to do anything additional to get pulseaudio to work on ubuntu server, or am I missing something else?